# How do I setup my Python Path so that pytest is able to find my Django 'manage.py' file?

Tags: python, django, docker, pytest

I'm a college student currently working on a small Django web app project and I'm trying to get pytest up and running on my container.

When I try to run pytest, I receive an error

```
pytest-django could not find a Django project (no manage.py file could be found). You must explicitly add your Django project to the Python path to have it picked up.
make: *** [pytest] Error 1
```

I'm wondering how to fix this error so that pytest is able to find my manage.py which is inside another folder.

I've tried messing with the settings a bit but to no avail. Here's what I tried in the manage.py file:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'timetracker'))
```

This is my project structure:

```
timetracker/
  |---- accounts/
  |---- timetracker/
          |---- settings.py
  |---- conftest.py
  |---- manage.py

docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
Makefile
pytest.ini
requirements.txt
```

Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE timetracker.settings
```

EDIT: Here is my pytest.ini file:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = timetracker.settings
addopts = -vv -s
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: How and with which working directory do you run the tests?

Comment: It's probably better to configure settings in pytest_setup, inside your conftest.py file...

Comment: @KlausD. I am running the tests via '$(compose) exec web pytest'  from the Makefile in the base directory.